# Favorite Tags Questions

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, tag-watching

My question appears to be silly. Is there a way to filter questions to my favorite tags? I know that I can select **one** of my tags and see its questions, but I want to see all questions in my tags together.

Comment: You can use [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/), however you lose markdown in this way. (Or you must add it somehow to view it.)

Comment: BTW here is an older similar question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/filtering-by-tag

Comment: The simplest solution seems to be searching for [intags:mine is:q](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aq). In this way you get list of all questions from your favorite tags.

Comment: @MartinSleziak many thanks, it is very helpful

Comment: @MartinSleziak yep, and imho it's worthy of adding as an answer

Comment: @TooTone In fact, it is already given as an answer in the linked question.

Comment: @TooTone I have no problem to accept his answer whenever Martin write it

Comment: @MartinSleziak aha I can see you've just edited in the magic. Nice one.